# What was the primary motive for using a chazzan who is musically skilled?

Tags: history, chazzan-prayer-leader

[O.C. 53:4](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=157) says that one of the requirements for a "proper"  *shaliach tzibbur* (shat"z) is that he have a "pleasant voice". (There are other qualities included.)

53:5 states that if one cannot find all the qualities for "proper", one should choose someone who is wise and has an abundance of good deeds. Rama adds that if they find an aged ignoramus who has a pleasant voice, and the people prefer him, they should use him.

I'm uncertain if the term "pleasant voice" equates with "musical skill" meaning at the least, the ability to sing on tune.

In much of Europe, esp. Vienna, they trained chazzanim in musical ability. Many of these "professional" chazzanim immigrated to the U.S., and many shuls specifically hired such chazzanim. This practice was quite common in U.S. shuls until about approximately 30 years ago, when it rapidly declined.

Considering that O.C. does not specifically mention that the shaliach tzibbur needs to be a "musical maestro", what was the main motive for training chazzanim to incorporate musical talent and for shuls to seek out this quality in a shaliach tzibbur? Was its motive to get the congregation more involved in joining in the prayers (which seems to contradict the true meaning of a "shaliach" which implies that he is appointed as your "messenger") or motivated by a career choice so that such people would be more likely to be hired by a shul?

Comment: FWIW, in some parts of Europe, knowledge of the material was more important than musical ability. Yossele Rosenblatt left the Hamburger Kahal because he wasn't allowed to embellish his chazzanus following the style he'd learned (Galitzianer chazzanus). http://guesswhoscoming2dinner.blogspot.com/2010/10/why-i-daven-with-yekkes-guest-post.html

Comment: I do not see anywhere in your question that proves that musical skill is neccessesary?

Comment: @GershonGold Yes. I'm not saying that it's necessary. I'm stating that it seems to have become high priority. Part of the question is whether the Mishnah Brurah's definition of "pleasant voice" includes musical skill.

Comment: Perhaps in some synagogues. However just because some places want a Chazan that has musical skill does not make it a part of the shaliach Tzibburs job. Thus I think your question is unclear.

Comment: Seems pretty hard to answer, social conventions shift, and it is difficult to pinpoint a particular reason, as different individuals who form that society ca have different reasons. While I didn't VTC, the vote does not seem unreasonable.

Comment: How is this off-topic? It's asking for the history of a particular Halacha.

Comment: @DonielF I made some major edits following mevaqesh's comment. *Dan Lekaf zechut* ;-)

Comment: @GershonGold Please inform me if the edits make the question clearer. I'm not suggesting that musical skill is halacha. I'm stating that at some point, this became common requirement.

Comment: @DanF I actually thought it was fine before...

Comment: @DanF The Rema says that if a community has an old ignorant person with a pleasant voice who the community wants and a Bar Mitzvah boy who understands what he is saying (meaning peirush HaMilot) and a voice which is not pleasant, they should use the Bar Mitzvah boy. The pleasant voice is a secondary attribute.

Comment: And if you look to the Sha'arey Teshuvah and the Mishnah Berurah to your citations, it is clear that the priority is to choose as the community representative, someone who will be effective in arousing mercy from above, not someone who has a good singing voice.

Comment: What do so many people have against this question that it keeps coming up in the close queue?

Comment: @DonielF Beats me... I wonder if I can place a bounty on a closed question :-)